# Using Android to Answer calls of iPhone

Tags: calls

My primary device has always been an iPhone. But recently i saw android auto and it is way more responsive and offers a great experience.

So I am planning to get an android tablet for my car. But the problem is that if I connect the android and not my iphone then I would not be able to take calls coming to the iphone on my car's speakers. Is there any way I can do this, something like handoff?

Call forwarding is not really an option as it would always forward my call to android tab which I do not want. I just want the phone calls to come on android when I am in the car (or iphone is nearby the android tab).

Hope there is something like this available!

Comment: http://www.mrhandsfree.com/en/customer-service/product-faq's/blue-multi-how-do-i-connect-2-mobile-phones-at-the-same-time-(multipoint-pairing)

Comment: @alecxs thanks! I read the link, it is a hardware change required in my car. I do not want that. Instead, I am looking for some application which can do this. I own a Jeep Compass and it already has a pretty good Uconnect system installed.

Comment: Some sort of Bluetooth Headset application is all i can think of... The IPhone sends out a Bluetooth signal for Headsets to receive the call... This was also one of the first methods of In-Car stereo connectivity after FM Transmitters died out...

Comment: @Zillinium yes that should work for me, let me explore it a bit more. Thanks for the suggestion.